# Dying Light - Awakening: Can't grab the ledge

Tags: dying-light

While following Rahim's tips, where the instruction says:"Hit Jump and Hold to grab the ledge", I can't reach the ledge. I just fall down.

What am I doing wrong? I'm a terrible gamer. please help.

Comment: You need to look at the ledge you want to grab onto, and jump at the very last moment, maybe it's that?

Comment: Ahh.. I had to run to reach the other side. my bad. thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the game gives you button instructions for making the jump without telling you to also run.

Comment: Don't feel bad, I think a lot of people got a faceful of concrete the first few times they tried the Parkour in this game.  Once you get used to it, the whole thing flows much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold down left joy stick that will make you run then it's easy to get. Took me a million times to understand that

Comment: Jesus I’m an idiot.  This took me way too long

Answer (score 4):

Although the instructions do not explicitly say this, jumping onto ledges often (usually) requires running first to gain sufficient speed to cover the distance, then holding space to grab the ledge.

Posting this as a wiki answer since it was answered ~9 months ago in a comment.